# Anti-random reals

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, logic, computability

**EDIT: This has now been crossposted at MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/219366/antirandom-reals.**

*This is partially motivated by my question at mathoverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/218810/relative-null-ness.*

For a function $f: \mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ and a set $X\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, an *$f$-cover of $X$* is a sequence $(I_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of open intervals with rational endpoints such that

- $X\subseteq\bigcup I_n$, and
- $\mu(I_n)<f(n)$.

Say that a set $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is *$f$-small* if $X$ has an $f$-cover.

Talking about $f$-covers provides us with many different refinements of the notion of "measure zero": e.g., a set is *strong measure zero* if it has an $f$-cover for *every* function $f$.

Say that a set of reals $X$ is *computably strong measure zero* (csmz) if there is an $e$ such that $\Phi_e^f$ is an $f$-cover of $X$ whenever $f$ is a function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. (This is sadly *not* the same as *effective strong measure zero*, a notion introduced by Kihara in his thesis; see also Higuchi and Kihara http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S016800721400044X.)

In computability theory, a real is said (informally) to be "random" if it is not in any "simple" measure-zero set; there are of course many ways to formalize this, but this is the basic theme. Csmz sets provide a very strong notion of non-randomness: say that an *individual* real $r$ is **antirandom** if $\{r\}$ is csmz - equivalently, if $r$ is contained in some csmz set. My question is:

> What are the antirandom reals?

I strongly suspect that every antirandom real is computable, but I can't prove it.

*TECHNICAL NOTE: the set of antirandom reals is countable - this is because there is a countable set $\{A_i: i\in\omega\}$ of csmz sets such that every csmz set is contained in one of the $A_i$s, it can be forced that every strong measure zero set is countable, and antirandomness is a $\Pi^1_1$ property (so "there are countably many antirandom reals" is absolute assuming large cardinals).*

Comment: I lost you when you got to csmz, because you used a term $e$ and then put it into another term $\Phi_e^f$. I'm not sure what set $e$ is being chosen from and what  $\Phi_e^f$ means.

Comment: This is standard notation in computability theory: $e$ is a natural number, and $\Phi_e^f$ is the $e$th Turing machine run with oracle $f$.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, I only took an intro theory of computation class. Unfortunately now that I have a better understanding of what you're asking, I have no idea how to characterize your antirandom reals. Looks like a good question though, I upvoted. =)

Comment: Thanks! (For your amusement: the old notation for "the $e$th Turing machine" was "$\{e\}$." Clearly, this never led to any confusion. :P)

Comment: Can you remind me what the definition of computable real is, because this strikes me as relatively easy to prove it it, say, means having a computable sequence of rationals converging to it which is computably Cauchy - that is, where the $N$ in the Cauchy criterion depends on $\epsilon$ in a computable way.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see how to prove that - can you elaborate? (A real is computable if its binary expansion is computable, so if you're right, that would answer my question.)

Comment: Oh, never mind, the problem is, you don't know which interval your number is in just by knowing $e$, so you can't obviously construct the rationals you need to construct the sequence.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Bingo. :) Annoyingly slippery, isn't it?

Comment: If you restrict your definition to $f$ computable, that gives a broader condition - there exists $e$ and computable $g$ so that for $f=\Phi_i$ then $\Phi_{g(e,i)}$ computes such a sequence when $f$ is total. Call such a set "c-csmz." Any "csmz" set is "c-csmz," but not necessarily visa-versa. It might be worth trying to first find a non-computable $\{x\}$ which is c-csmz.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews That's a good idea - I think it won't be too hard to construct such reals. By the way, a bit of (possibly unfortunate) terminology: the paper by Higuchi and Kihara I mention defines a set $X$ to be *effective strong measure zero* if it is non-uniformly c-csmz, that is, for each computable $f$ there is an $f$-cover, but that cover need not be computable, let alone uniformly computable.

Comment: If you force a random real $r$, and take an antirandom real $s$. What is $r+s$? Is it $0$? :-)